# xcode 8.1 debug symbols missing

Tags: swift, xcode, perfect, swift-package-manager

When generating projects with swift package manager (specifically https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git) that have an executable (a main.swift), I loose the ability to access local debug symbols when using Xcode 8.1 and later (see below, image 1). Is this specific to the PerfectTemplate and/or is there a fix I can implement?

I've tried this on Xcode 8.1 and 8.2, Swift 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 PREVIEW 1. Also, my optimization level is set to none (see below, image 2). This was not a problem prior to Xcode 8.1, that is, at the same breakpoint shown below the local symbol table did populate. Also, when I lldb the swift build directly for the perfect template executable, the local symbol populates for 3.0.2 but not for 3.0.1 (see below, image 3). And finally, for all other non-executable Xcode projects, SPM or otherwise, both Xcode versions and Swift versions debug properly and generate the local symbol table.

Image 1 (missing local symbols):
[image]
Image 2 (build optimization levels):
[image]
Image 3 (successful lldb for 3.0.2):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months ago but Im not sure what I did to resolve it.

First check your Xcode & swift enabled version:
Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools.

[image: Command line settings]

Then try a fresh version (with very last sources)

Clone the project again:

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git
```

Build it

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
open PerfectTemplate.xcodeproj
```

Run it and check the symbols.

It works for me with Xcode 8.2.1, swift version 3.0.2.

I hope it help you.